# Saving changes to eagerly loaded associations in RIA Services

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, wcf-ria-services

I'm using RIA Services with Entity Framework for the data layer of my Silverlight application.  I have two entities that are related in a many-to-one relationship

```
public class Installation
{
    [Key]
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Column("District")]
    public Guid? DistrictID { get; set; }

    [Include]
    [Association("InstallationDistrict", "DistrictID", "DistrictID")]
    public District District { get; set; }
}

public partial class District
{
    [Key]
    public Guid DistrictID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

I am using EF Code First for my entities.

Here is the code for the service:

```
[EnableClientAccess]
public class EagerLoadingService : DomainService
{
    private readonly CentralContext _context;
    public EagerLoadingService()
    {
        _context = new CentralContext();
    }
    [Query]
    public IQueryable GetInstallations()
    {
        return _context.Installations.Include("District");
    }
    [Update]
    public void UpdateInstallation(Installation i)
    {
        _context.Installations.Find(i.Serial).District = i.District;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    [Query]
    public IQueryable GetDistricts()
    {
        return _context.Districts;
    }
}
```

When loading an Installation, I include the associated District, which works fine (I'm getting the entity on the client side).  However, when I change the District on the client and try to update, the HasChanged flag is still false on the entity and the service context, and the associated foreign key doesn't change (DistrictID on the Installation record).

Is there a way to get this to work the way I'm expecting it to?

Comment: Probably the Districts are being detached for some reason. Check EntityState for the one that you're trying to save.

Comment: EntityState is Unmodified.  Maybe it's something to do with the way I set up my entities.  I'll update and add some more detail on the entity classes.

Comment: Maybe the validation is failing for the field you're modifying. Try opening the generated code file for the service (Generated_Code folder) and set a breakpoint in the setter for that property.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to go to the generated code.  Turns out that without IsForeignKey = true in the property, it doesn't generate code to set the foreign key on the entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was doing the Association attribute incorrectly.  It needed to be

```
[Association("InstallationDistrict", "DistrictID", "DistrictID", IsForeignKey = true)]
```

Thanks to [this guide](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/alexb/archive/2011/01/27/a-guide-through-wcf-ria-services-attributes.aspx) for pointing it out.